Categorizing the terms "Parallel", "Concurrent", "Synchronous" and "Asynchronous" using Venn diagrams
Concurrency, parallelism, synchronous, and asynchronous are terms that I have come across at various places but have never quite fully understood the true distinction between them. I have seen all four terms used interchangeably and also done some research on what exactly all of them mean. I found quite satisfactory results1 explaining what each term meant, and also their definitions. But what is still not clear to me, is how exactly would we differentiate them if we had to represent them through a Venn diagram.
My current understanding is the following -

All parallel things are concurrent, but all concurrent things are not parallel.
No synchronous things are asynchronous, and vice-versa.
Some synchronous things are concurrent, and some synchronous things are parallel.
All asynchronous things are concurrent, but only some asynchronous things are parallel.


My question is whether my current understanding of the difference is correct. If not, how must they be categorized and why?

1I watched Rob Pike's video on Concurrency is not Parallelism. And the following response on Reddit explaining the difference between synchronous and asynchronous code. I have tried to summarize my findings in a blog post if you're willing to go through it.

I would not put "parallel" entirely inside "concurrent." Guy in the video said, "Concurrency is the composition of independently executing things." (My emphasis on, "independently.") If you have a symmetric multi-processor computer that is concurrently executing several different threads on several different processors, that's one form of parallelism. But parallelism can come in other forms where the parallel executions are not independent from each other. That kind of parallelism happens a lot in signal processing and image processing systems that use specialized computing hardware.

While categorizing three or more terms is useful sometimes, you are better to ask about only two terms at once. E.g. there is the question on Stack Overflow about difference of parallel and concurrent aspects, which covers your first point. As usual, a good question post on Stack Overflow has only single question.

@Tsyvarev I understand that a good post must have a single question, however, I am trying to properly explain these concepts to my peers, and I often struggle to relate them. I can easily explain what any one of the terms means and also how it is different from another. But there is no concrete picture like a Venn diagram that explains the precise relation between all of them.
